# Alamofire, Use of undeclared type

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, alamofire

I added Alamofire manually to my workspace. I went through the steps, I added the framework and Target dependencies except I couldn't find embedded binaries section in my workspace target. 
Now I keep getting "Use of undeclared Type" error every time I attempt to use a class or enum declared in Alamofire[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wipe DerivedData for starters.